# use pyspark to shuffle random selected columns

Tags: pyspark

I was trying to do:

1. random select a few columns from the DataFrame
2. shuffle the value from the column select from step 1
3. add these columns from step 2 back to the DataFrame

The code is as following:

```
# Step 0: create data frame using list and tuple
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
        ("user1", 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
        ("user2", 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
        ("user3", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
        ("user4", 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
        ("user5", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
        ("user6", 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
    ], ["ID", "x0", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9"])

df.show()
```

The DataFrame is:

[image]

```
import random
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# define features
feature = [x for x in df.columns if x not in ['ID']]

# Step 1: random select a few columns from the DataFrame
random.seed(123)
random_col = random.sample(feature, 2)
print(random_col)
```

Step 1 works well. The random selected feature are 'x0', 'x4'

```
# shuffle the random selected columns to create random noise feature
for i in range(0, 2):
    # Step 2: shuffle the value from the column select from step 1
    rnd_df = df.select(random_col[i]).orderBy(F.rand(i)).withColumnRenamed(random_col[i], 'rnd_col').rnd_col
    # step 3: add these columns from step 2 back to the DataFrame
    df = df.withColumn('random'+ str(i+1), rnd_df)
```

Step 2 works well. But Step 3 fails with the following error. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: You cannot add a external column to a dataframe it does not belong to except if you perform a join.

Comment: I guess so. but how to add a column by shuffling one of the existing columns?

Comment: actually the column is derived from the original table

Comment: you create an id for each line (1 to N). You shuffle your new column, then add an id for each line (1 to N) and join on that id ...